# Will gerrit notify if previous reviews are accepted or not

Tags: git, gerrit

I am using gerrit as pre-commit review tool. I have a scenario:

Commit 1: Line 8 in File A changed.
          Line 20 in File A changed
Commit 2: Line 8 in File A changed

Now when I submit both of them for review, commit 1 will be reviewed against File A in repo as base while commit 2 is reviewed keeping commit 1 changes as base.

Now, when I accept commit 2, will gerrit notify me that commit 1 is not reviewed and that Line 20 is still unreviewed?

Answer (score 0):

We can see the following to understand your commit history.

```
A---B
```

Let's A is commit 1 and B is commit 2. In this case, B is cling to A. So, you need to accept A and then accept B again. In short, based on commit dependency, Gerrit let you know what you should do right now.

Comment: How is this notified. I tried this and did a +2 on B (before A) and it perfectly allowed me, while it should've ideally warned me to review commit A first. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Oh, I see. As far as I know, Gerrit only notifies you warning when you are trying to press submit button on a commit which has dependency on another un-submitted commit. Otherwise, it does not tell you anything. However, I don't know the recent version of Gerrit.

Comment: Commit A will be listed as a dependency of commit B. In the old change screen the dependencies are listed between the reviewer list and the patch sets and in the new change screen (optional even in Gerrit 2.10) it's IIRC on the right in the top row.